# Force login after password reset in Keycloak 18.0.2

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-spi

I am using Keyclaok 18.0.2 and when a user clicks on "Forgot Password?" it receives an email for the password update. The problem is that after the new password is created, the user is automatically being login. I am trying to avoid that and try to make the login manually. Because there is no option to do it via the Keycloak manager, I tried to use SPI, and listen for the event responsible for that.

What I did is to remove the session for the specific realm and user. Unfortunately, nothing happened.

```
public class PasswordResetEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

  private final KeycloakSession session;
  private final RealmModel realm;

  public PasswordResetEventListenerProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
      this.session = session;
      this.realm = session.getContext().getRealm();
  }

  @Override
  public void onEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.getType() == EventType.LOGIN) {

      UserModel user = session.users().getUserById(event.getUserId(),     session.getContext().getRealm());
      session.sessions().removeUserSessions(realm,user);

    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried to remove all the authentication directly by removing the cookies. But still nothing happened as if I was trying to get the ***request*** and ***response*** from the context, it was returning  java.lang.NullPointerException. I tried to find a different way to get them, but I could not find one for Keycloak version 18.0.2

```
for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
  if (cookie.getName().startsWith("KEYCLOAK_")) {
      cookie.setValue("");
      cookie.setMaxAge(0);
      cookie.setPath("/");
      cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
      cookie.setSecure(request.isSecure());
      response.addCookie(cookie);
  }
}

HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);
if (httpSession != null) {
  httpSession.invalidate();
}
```

Do you think that this one of this cases is a good approach. Is there another way to make the user login manually after the password reset?